# Sum of Excel Range Between Dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, range

So I've struggled with this problem several times and usually just end up giving up on it, but this time I want to solve the problem once and for all. I have a straightforward table as follows:

```
Date    | Item    | Value
---------------------------
        | Total   |  $0.00
8/10/15 | Thing A | -$10.00
8/11/15 | Thing B | -$20.00
8/12/15 | Thing C | -$30.00
8/13/15 | Thing D | -$40.00
8/13/15 | Thing E | -$50.00
8/15/15 | Thing F | -$60.00
```

What I want to be able to do is put a date in `A2` (the first cell below `Date`) and compute the sum of `C3` through the last cell in the `C` column whose corresponding `A` column value matches `A2`. Does that make sense?

An example would be putting in `8/13/2015` would update `C2` to `-$150.00` because it sums up `C3` through `C7` because `A7` is the last row that has `8/13/2015` in it.

I hope what I'm asking is clear. I appreciate any help you provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On `C2` put the following formula:

`=SUMIFS(C3:C8;A3:A8;"<="&A2)`

It will sum the cells in the range `C3:C8`, but only those corresponding a match among the range `A3:A8` and the condition `<=A2`.

For the condition the comparative operator `<=` must be surrounded in quotation marks and the reference cell `A2` must be preceded by an ampersand symbol (&).